# Synchronize the time setting of my laptop with the time shown in a website with millisecond accuracy

Tags: javascript, ubuntu-14.04, windows-7-x64, clock, clock-synchronization

I have this problem that the time setting of my laptop does not match the one of a website with millisecond accuracy. Also, I do not know which server that website gets its time setting from.

Is there any way to synchronize my laptop with the time shown on the website with millisecond accuracy?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need down to the millisecond accuracy?  I do not think this is truly possible ( to the millisecond ).

Comment: Also what is your operating system?

Comment: @MisterPositive . Well I need to purchase an item on that website by clicking a link at a certain time with millisecond accuracy, and I am writing a code to auto-click, but as I said the problem is that I can only auto-click according to the time setting of my laptop.

Comment: @MisterPositive For example when I click at 12:00:00:000 [hour,minute,second,millisecond], the click would be at 12:00:00:300 according to the time setting of that website and the lag varies from time to time. I was wondering if it is possible to get the time setting of the website using Javascript.

Comment: @GabrielHautclocq . Windows 7. And Please tell me if it is possible in Linux.